# When migrating truffle second time, I get "Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:"

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

When I first run `truffle migrate` yesterday, it worked. But today I am getting this error:

```
- host       > 127.0.0.1
- port       > 8545
- network_id > *
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)
```

I did not change the truffle.config.js.

```
development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*", // Any network (default: none)
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

before deploying you have to run ganache-cli or any other client similar to it.
try `truffle develop` before `truffle migrate`

```
develop: {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 8545,
  network_id: "*",
```